# Prologue with Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a total newbie to RoR and am trying to get the **Prologue** gem up and running. I've downloaded the prologue zip file from github.com/quickleft/prologue and am trying to follow the instructions in the associated readme file. I have encountered a number of issues....

Q1: What do I actually do with the extracted zip file? For instance, am I supposed to place the extracted files inside specific rails application directories or what ?

I've  been able to install the gem by executing "gem install prologue". However, I cannot create a new application using the "prologue new my_app" command - the following message is displayed at the command prompt when I execute that command:

*C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/prologue-0.3.10/lib/prologue/cli.rb:58:in ``
': No such file or directory - git config --global user.name (Errno::ENOENT)

from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/prologue-0.3.10/lib/prologue/cli.rb:58:in `git_user_name'

from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/prologue-0.3.10/lib/prologue/cli.rb:33:in `new'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/task.rb:22 :in`run'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:118:in invoke_task'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/base.rb:38 
9:in`start'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/prologue-0.3.10/bin/prologue:4: in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby192/bin/prologue:19:in`load'
from C:/Ruby192/bin/prologue:19:in `'*

Q2: Does anyone have any advice on how to overcome this problem?

Q3: Also, when attempting to get prologue up and running is it possible to do this without integrating it into an existing rails application? If so, how?

(I have ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.0.0 installed on a Windows Vista machine)

Advice/feedback on the above issues would be greatly welcome!

Comment: Do you have Git installed on this system?  May be part of the problem...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Prologue needs 'thor', another gem. You can install all dependencies with the command 'bundle install'.

You can integrate Prologue in a new Rails app, but you definitely need some (existing or new) Rails app to run it.